# c++ float vector does not recognize float number?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

I have following code which that initialize a float vector:

```
std::vector<float> arr= { -11, -12, -45.3, -34.5, 110, 5, 10,3 ,22, 100, 1, 23 };
```

However I am get a compiling error:

```
 error C2398: Element '3': conversion from 'double' to 'float' requires a narrowing conversion
```

If I change the third element -45.3 to -45 like following:

```
std::vector<float> arr= { -11, -12, -45, -34.5, 110, 5, 10,3 ,22, 100, 1, 23 };
```

The compilation is successful.

I am wondering where the problem is? Why -45.3 is not recognized as a float here? Because -34.5 is a similar case.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: It [compiles](https://godbolt.org/g/CehCKg) on GCC 7.2 (C++11)